# ag-Grid server-side row model with Redux integration

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

How does one setup a server-side row model in ag-Grid when using a Redux store as the source of truth?

On the ag-Grid website two guides are available:

1. a guide on how to setup a grid with a server-side row model. This guide is given [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-server-side-model-datasource/) and it's not React / Redux specific. As such, it follows an imperative style and I am not sure it can be made to work with Redux.
2. a guide on how to setup ag-Grid with React / Redux. This guide is given [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-redux-integration-pt1/) but seems to apply exclusively to a client-side row model.

How could one go about using a server-side row model in ag-Grid with Redux integration or is such an approach ill-advised given that the ag-Grid framework apparently does not cater to this?

Comment: @HMR I am not doing server-side rendering. Server-side row model in ag-Grid is unrelated to server-side rendering. It simply means that the rows to be displayed in a grid are filtered / sorted on the server as opposed to the browser (i.e. inside the grid component itself).